# Does setting techOrder for video.js really work?

Tags: video.js

Due to some IE problems, I'm trying to force video.js to use a techOrder that puts Flash first (at least when IE is being used, anyway).  I've tried all the methods mentioned in https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/tech.md, and none of them are working for me.  I'm also finding a lot of people asking the same general question in various tech sites, with no responses to any of them, other than some version of "didn't work for me, either".  I've been able to get the Flash player to work by hacking the video.js source, but this is obviously the wrong route, since I want to use html5 in the non-IE cases.

So: has anybody been able to make this work?  Any examples out there?

Answer (score 2):

Both the data-setup and options block methods are working for me.

```
data-setup='{ "techOrder":["flash", "html5"] }'
```

In the data-setup method make sure you're using single quotes around the HTML attribute value and double quotes in the JSON. JSON requires double.

The techOrder is just a preference, and isn't guaranteed. It still depends on which tech and video formats are supported by the specific browser. If this doesn't help, can you give more specifics about your use case, and copy/paste your code from your first attempts?

Comment: Here's my video tag: `<video id='player' class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls preload='auto' width='938' height='528'
  poster='http://example.com/poster.jpg'
  data-setup='{"customControlsOnMobile": true, "techOrder":["flash", "html5"]}'>
  <source src='http://example.com/video.mp4' type='video/mp4' />
</video>` .  My main concern is getting this working in IE, although I pulled this from the Source window of Mac Chrome (which is able to run the Flash version if I feed it a properly hacked video.js file).  I've found a workaround, but it'd be nice to get this working as intended. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't get the data-setup method to work either, but I was able to get it to work by setting `videojs.options`:

```
<video .... />
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.4/video.js"></script>
<script>
  videojs.options.techOrder = ['flash', 'html5'];
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue can be solved setting the correct `type.
Setting the correct type allow the videojs plugin to automaticallt detect if the fallback is required or not. ( so you don't need to change the techorder but just do as follow )

For example this define a video encoded with h.264

```
videojs('my-videoid').src(
            {type: 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E"', src: 'myvideoh264.avi'}
        );
```

Reference about codec info:
[How to detect supported video formats for the HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451635/how-to-detect-supported-video-formats-for-the-html5-video-tag)