# Windows 10 Safari HTML5 Video canPlayType

Tags: html, audio, video, safari

Safari (version 5.1.7) on Windows 10 does not [support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451635/how-to-detect-supported-video-formats-for-the-html5-video-tag) html video and audio, but works well with same version on Windows 7, so you have to use flash to play html media in this case. This seems like quite a drawback or I am missing something. Is there a way around it?

http://jsfiddle.net/jxajbo6f/2/

```
var testEl = document.createElement( "video" ),
if ( testEl.canPlayType )
```

Comment: My guess is you are missing that Safari 5.1.7 is ancient. Version 9 is the latest, and I don't think Apple even distributes the old Windows version anymore.

Comment: I am aware, but this is the latest (better say last) version for windows and some users still access web on windows using safari so you have to think about it all.

Answer (score 0):

The number of users using safari on Windows 10 is going to be fairly small - Safari version less than 6 have less than 0.5% of total market share across all OS's according to this market share site for example:

- https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0&qpct=3&qpcustomb=

It could still be important for you, however, if you have a target audience or organisation that do need to use it for some reason.

The problem is that the HTML5 video standards and extensions keep evolving so a browser not being developed, as Alexander points out above, simply cannot maintain compatibility.

In addition to this the OS itself has been updated and may provide new or different mechanisms to playback videos, for example leveraging HW acceleration and allowing for DRM, and only limited support may be offered for older interfaces. Falling back to Flash looks like your best alternative if you really have to support this use case.