# Hide video with jQuery if WebM is not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This would be my idea:

```js
if webm is not supportet {
  $("video").css("display", "none");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<video src="video.webm" poster="image.png" playsinline muted autoplay loop></video>
```

Is it possible to hide a video if WebM is not supported? If yes, how?

With only CSS, it also would be fine.

Would be veeeery thankful for help!

Comment: Have a look [here](https://davidwalsh.name/detect-supported-video-formats-javascript)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect supported video formats for the HTML5 video tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7451635/how-to-detect-supported-video-formats-for-the-html5-video-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a video element or take an existing one and check with the `canPlayType()` function:

```
var elem = document.createElement( "video" )
canPlayWebM = "" !== testEl.canPlayType( 'video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' )
if (!canPlayWebM)  {
  $("video").css("display", "none");
}
```

More info on the function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canPlayType)

Comment: I would like to use the existing video, like in my example. Unfortunately, I have problems to combine this. How can I write that?

Comment: it doesn't matter which video. It checks if the browser can play any webM video. I updated the answer a bit

Comment: Unfortunately, my question was closed, and I can't accept your answer. But I also would have a further one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66465452/12501851